# Menu in a popup window gets deactivated by central widget

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a simple popup window with a popup menu activated by a button on the top and a list in the rest of the window. I came up with the following simplified code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MenuWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, flags=QtCore.Qt.Widget, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, flags=flags)

        self.popup_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)

        self.action1 = QtWidgets.QAction('Action1', self)
        self.action1.triggered.connect(self.do_action1)
        self.action2 = QtWidgets.QAction('Action2', self)
        self.action2.triggered.connect(self.do_action2)

        self.popup_menu.addAction(self.action1)
        self.popup_menu.addAction(self.action2)
        self.menu_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.menu_button.setMenu(self.popup_menu)
        self.menu_button.setPopupMode(QtWidgets.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('test')
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.menu_button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def do_action1(self):
        print('Doing action1')

    def do_action2(self):
        print('Doing action2')


class MenuTesting(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, flags=QtCore.Qt.Window, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, flags=flags)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)

        self.tester = MenuWidget(parent=self)
        self.setMenuWidget(self.tester)

        self.somelist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(parent=self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.somelist)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MenuTesting()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But the problem is that the menu items aren't activated at all if a click is done on the part of the menu inside of the window. Outside of the window it works correctly. This problem exists on Windows 7 with Python 3.5.2 and PyQt 5.6.0 installed via Miniconda. However, the code works as expected on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (stable) with Python 3.4.2 and PyQt 5.3.2 from stock repositories. It doesn't matter which widget is set as central.

Is it a good practice to arrange widgets this way? What can be done to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in pyqt 5.6.0-py35_0, update to py35_1 helped.